# undefined:1 syntax error: unexpected token < in json at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, api, request

[image]

```
let options = {
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': `https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=${row.pincode}&date=${day}`,
                'headers': {
                    
                }
                
            };
request(options, function (error, re) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('error in request',error)
                    }
                    else if(re) {
                        let data = JSON.parse(re.body);
                        console.log(data)
                    }
})
```

It's working fine in localhost, but when I'm hosting it on digital ocean server, sometime the code executes sometimes it doesn't, it happens with the same code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting html code instead of json in your api response. Add this to headers

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
```

also try checking the html that you got, it can possibly provide you with a clue why you are getting it